# how to record webcam video with opencv2.4.9?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

 namedWindow("MyVideo",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

   double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
   double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

   cout << "Frame Size = " << dWidth << "x" << dHeight << endl;

   Size frameSize(static_cast<int>(dWidth), static_cast<int>(dHeight));

 VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("D:/MyVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'), 20, frameSize, true); //initialize the VideoWriter object 

   if ( !oVideoWriter.isOpened() ) //if not initialize the VideoWriter successfully, exit the program
   {
        cout << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
        return -1;
   }

    while (1)
    {

        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
       {
             cout << "ERROR: Cannot read a frame from video file" << endl;
             break;
        }

         oVideoWriter.write(frame); //writer the frame into the file

        imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        if (waitKey(10) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
       {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break; 
       }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I am developing this project using Visual Studio 2012 express and opencv_2.4.9 and windows 7 x64.

But, this code is not working.

Just write out this message "ERROR: Failed to write the video".

Comment: try finding out where the error occurs, maybe with cout << mesages after each step.

Comment: Try running with admin privileges.

Comment: Two things: 1) Use a codec that is installed on your machine, `PIM1` is probably not. Try `MJPG` or `MPEG`. 2) Check file path. Windows uses "\\" AFAIK, which means your file path should be `D:\\myvideo.avi`.

Comment: Thanks   a lot.. x64 dll folder into x32 dll . sorry, i'm so stupid....

Answer (score 0):

Use try, catch to see if you can get a more detailed error message.

One thing I remember when writing videos is that you need to verify you have the codecs installed and in the correct directory or added as a PATH environment variable.

`opencv_ffmpeg.dll` was the issue for me, and making sure it was in the correct directory and being renamed to `opencv_ffmpeg249.dll`